# MVVM - Reuse Views with multiple ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

I believe one of the main benefits of MVVM is decoupling, the binding and lack of references makes things a lot more reusable.

All MVVM examples I find have some kind of View with a ViewModel with the same naming like `ExampleView` has a `ExampleViewModel`. And always a one to one relationship, one View, one ViewModel.

But in my current project I have a form to be filled so data can be added to the data base, also the user has the option to edit the data on the data base, so this form View can be used transparently with two different ViewModels, one for adding data and one for editing data. I find it a little stupid to copy and paste and entire View just to have it named after its ViewModel, and not only that, if I need to change something, it will always have to be twice the work and stuff might be forgotten.

Some frameworks have a ViewModel locator that will use this same naming convention to bind the View with the ViewModel automatically, and this makes me question the reusability of Views with many different ViewModels.

My question basically is: Is it there a problem in using one View with different ViewModels? Is it bad practice? Are there any naming conventions to this particular situation?

The lack of examples on reusability makes me question the validity of this practice.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem - the view is knowledgable of the view model but not vice versa. This is fine with what you're doing.

I would however create an interface of the common binding properties in both view models then a view model locator to expose the instance as a property. That means your binding to the implementation but don't care which one.

How you toggle that implementation depends on how you instantiate your view.

Comment: Currently I am not using a ViewModel Locator, I am instantiating the VM and the View myself.

Comment: @mFeinstein : When you instantiate the View you can change its DataContext property assigning the VM instance of your choice, or you can define constructors to do this job for you and perhaps other VM dependent View initializations

Comment: Do you have any examples on this? I can't think of this without violating encapsulation, since the view constructor will have a reference to the view model directly.

Comment: This is where ViewModelLocator comes in. You create a datasource that exposes the instance as a property and bind to that. The property is typed as per your interface. If you want to swap between editable and non editable, create two properties. The implementation is still seperated and you effectively toggle based on view requirements - I would look to control this with a trigger to reset the datacontext in XAML, rather than on constructor too, but would need to test that :)

Answer (score 2):

**Perhaps you should use a user-control instead of a view.**

You can then embed a user-control into your views.
A user-control is not intended for view-model binding.
It's intended to be plugged into other containers.

In your case, you have different uses for this control based on the state of your business model.

Comment: In my case I have 2 Windows, both are only a form with places to fill and a button to submit an another to cancel. I thought about using it as user controls, but it seemed to be too much more work for just 2 reuses. I will have to create the control with all the dependency objects and bindings and then just make an empty window with the control, I don't know, it just didn't felt right, it feels just like a lot more work I think...

Comment: The same use-case is done with a textbox or a button. They're reusable. So is your form. Why does that feel wrong?

Comment: Because it's a huge form and I will have to bind all the textboxes with properties in the code behind of the usercontrol so later I can make a dependency property of all the textboxes so when I place the user control in a container it can bind all its stuff to the view model, I will use it in just 2 view models, so I will have a lot of work to Reuse just once, so I don't see the point in having so much work for avoiding work... Unless I miss understood something...

Comment: Have you added validation logic to your form? What's the likelihood that your form will require updates once it's released into production? People that take shortcuts pay for it later. Remember the DRY principle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: I'm with Scott, break everything into reusable usercontrols and inject one or more parts into each view as needed.  This goes for the user controls too as they themselves can contain other usercontrols.  The ultimate solution is one that has lots of singly responsible re-usable parts.

Comment: For a big project I will do it for sure, but for this one, it will be too much cumbersome and I rather to remain practical.

Answer (score 2):

As said in kidshaw answer:

Assuming that `NewExampleViewModel` and `EditExampleViewModel` share the same `IExampleViewModel` interface (whose properties are referenced by the view) and you strict don't want violate encapsulation, you can do it as:

```
var view = new ExampleView();
...
var NewVM = new NewExampleViewModel(...);
...
view.DataContext = NewVM;
...
  (or)
var EditVM = new EditExampleViewModel(...);
view.DataContext = EditVM;
...
```

Note that you can't use `IExampleViewModel` as `DesignInstance` in the view, as:

```
<UserControl ...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vmi:IExampleViewModel}"
```

to do that you need a concrete type, so you don't have IDE support in define the bindings.

You could use `NewExampleViewModel` or `EditExampleViewModel` as `DesignInstance` only while designing the view so to have IDE binding support, then remove it for the encapsulation principle.

Comment: I am already instantiating it as in your code, and I don't use the design instance... So what's the necessity for the interface?

Comment: There's not necessity for the interface, but if you intend to reuse the view with another view model, having the interface facilitate you the work to know the name should have the view model's properties to bind the view control's attributes. You can view it as a documentation of how use the View. @mFeinstein

Comment: Oh yes, it does help.... What do you think about the naming? I don't think there is a convention for this case of Reuse..

Comment: @mFeinstein I don't know about conventions for these cases, but I think the one I suggested in the answer examples could be a good one